# python range/xrange on 2d numpy array

Tags: python, numpy, matrix, range

I am confused by using range/xrange to subsetting a numpy matrix. The following code:

```
import numpy as np
A = np.array([[1, 2, 3, 4],[5, 6, 7, 8],[9, 10, 11, 12],[13, 14, 15, 16]])
A[range(2, 4), range(2, 4)]
A[2:4, 2:4]
```

The third line returns: `array([11, 16])`, while the fourth line returns:

```
array([[11, 12],
       [15, 16]])
```

Why is the difference here?

Comment: `:` is a synonym for `slice`, not `range`.  There is no reason your third and fourth lines should be the same.

Comment: The third line is `A[[2,3], [2,3]]`, an example of `advanced indexing`.  It returns `A[2,2]` and `A[3,3]`.  The fourth line is `basic indexing` with slices.